# how to limit list of sprites in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am just learning pygame and I've run into a problem. My program creates a fleet of aliens that you have to destroy. And I want to spawn the whole fleet just after complete removal, but my program spawns a ship at once when you destructed of another one.

I've tried to limit the list using while len < 48, but it didn't work.
This is program that spawns aliens at once (I also inserted it before the main loop):

```
 def create_fleet(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, aliens):
   alien = Alien(custom_settings, screen)
   number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(custom_settings, alien.rect.width)
   number_rows = get_number_rows(custom_settings, spaceship.rect.height, alien.rect.height) #!!!
   for row_number in range(number_rows):
       for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
           if len(aliens) < 48:
                create_alien(custom_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)
```

[New ships spawn in the left top verge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vs4z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want to spawn the whole fleet just after complete removal [...]

So you've to start to create the alien fleet, once the number of aliens is 0 ( len(aliens) == 0`) e.g.:

```py
def create_fleet(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, aliens):

      if len(aliens) == 0:

          alien = Alien(custom_settings, screen)
          number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(custom_settings,alien.rect.width)
          number_rows = get_number_rows(custom_settings,spaceship.rect.height,alien.rect.height)

          for row_number in range(number_rows):
              for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                  if len(aliens) < 48:
                      create_alien(custom_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)
```